# How can I delete changes from an overlay fs?

Tags: busybox, overlayfs

I have an embedded device running BusyBox, there are a number of directories mounted with `overlayfs` with work and data directories mounted on separate UBI partitions using the following style of command.

The main root filesystem is a `squashfs` read only image that's been updated with a newer version. I need to delete the changes that have been made to certain files so that the changes to `squashfs` take place. How can I do that?

```
mount -t overlay etc_overlay -o lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/mnt/config/.data,workdir=/mnt/config/.work /etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folders in /mnt/config/.data and /mnt/config/.work contain your changes. You can move them out of the way to create new ones. Unmount the overlay and remount it with a clean upper dir:

```
umount /etc
mv /mnt/config/.data /mnt/config/.data.old
mv /mnt/config/.work /mnt/config/.work.old
mkdir /mnt/config/.data
mkdir /mnt/config/.work
mount -t overlay etc_overlay -o lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/mnt/config/.data,workdir=/mnt/config/.work /etc
```

All of your changes to the old overlay will be found in `/mnt/config/.data.old` if you need them. `/mnt/config/.work.old` should be empty aside from the work folder if unmounted properly.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be something like this but wasn't sure. Tried it and it does exactly what I want it to.